# Manipulate HTML elements in index.html through php file

Tags: php, email, dom, contact-form

I made a simple contact form and I am trying to figure out how to change the html elements on the page to create a confirmation for when the e-mail is sent. As of now, it just reloads the page if an e-mail is sent. I would also like error messages to appear beside the input label as an html element if the name section is blank or e-mail entered is not valid.

This is the code that I have currently:

HTML:

```
<div id="contact-content" class="format-div">
    <form id="contact-form" action="/contact-form.php" method="post">
        <label for="contact-name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="contact-name" name="nameIn" placeholder="Enter 
       your name!">
        <label for="email-address">E-mail</label>
        <input type="text" id="email-address" name="emailIn" placeholder="Enter your e-mail address!">
        <label for="contact-message">Message</label>
        <textarea id="contact-message" name="messageIn" placeholder="All this space to fill with words..."
                  style="height:200px"></textarea>
        <button type="submit" name="submit-mail"><i class="far fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
    </form>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit-mail'])) {

    $name = $_POST['nameIn'];
    $address = $_POST['emailIn'];
    $message = $_POST['messageIn'];
    $error = "";

    if($name == '') $error .= 'Please fill in your name';

    if (!filter_var($address, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) $error .= 'The e-mail is invalid';

    $mailTo = "myemail@mysite.come";
    $subject = "FROM WEBSITE: ".$name;
    $header = "Mail from: ".$name.", ".$address."\n\n";

    mail($mailTo, $subject, $message, $header);
    header("Location: index.html?mailsent");
}
```

[What I am going for with error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hvwp4.png)

Comment: i think your code has a java script part that is not being shown

Answer (score 0):

Inside a HTML tag you can put this: `<php if (isset($_POST['submit-mail'])) { echo $error; } ?>` so if theres an error it will show inside the HTML tag

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your html page basically at the top perhaps you should catch the GET variable, if it was set. also you can display error similarly.

```
if(isset($_GET['mailsent'])){echo "Email Sent";} else if(isset($error)){echo $error;}
```

Also if index.html is not the page that has the form code then it will not have access to the error variable so.

change `header("Location: index.html?mailsent");` to `header("Location: index.html?error=".$error."&mailsent=");`

and because your html page will need to parse php ideally it should be a php page i.e index.php

```
header("Location: index.php?error=".$error."&mailsent=");
```

of course rename the index.html page to index.php. if u do not want to do it then take the JavaScript approach.